# How do I dynamically add tinymce to a php page without preloading it?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tinymce

I am working on a PHP project that displays a list of steps in a checklist. When someone clicks the edit button, I have a bootstrap modal popup with a tinymce editor for them to edit the existing record.

My issue is because I am trying to figure out an efficient way to retrieve end edit the data for that individual step. Right now my code works, but when the page loads, it needs to initialize a tinymce instance for every instance in my loop.

Is there a way for me to get my modal to work outside of the loop I wrote, in other words, I want to figure out how to pass php data into a single modal/tinymce instance.

Here is the sample code that I am working on:

```
<form method="post">
    <button id="add">Add</button>
</form>
<div class="container steps"id="sortable">
    <?php foreach($list as $l): ?>
    <?php $id = $l->id; ?>
    <div id="step-<?php echo $l->id;?>">
        <div name="<?php echo $l->id;?>">
            <div  class="content"><?php echo $l->step_text; ?></div>
            <span class="editable" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#test-<?php echo $id;?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
            <span class="remove"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="test-<?php echo $id;?>">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button  class="btn btn-danger lose" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
                <h2>STEP: <?php echo $l->step;?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="../processes/save.php" method="post">
                    <textarea name="checklist" id="stuff" class="TinyMCE"><?php echo $l->step_text; ?></textarea>
                    <input type="hidden" name="cid" value=<?php echo $l->id;?>>
                    <input type="submit" value="Save">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Proper, clean, formatted code will always be more useful than non-formatted code.

Comment: Sounds like an AJAX request?

Comment: thank you, I did a little more digging on ajax got what I needed to get my code working properly